# CRUD operations on a Cosmos DB from a Blazor Server App

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, blazorise

In the Blazor application I am developing, I have code that performs the basic CRUD operations.

```
 <ButtonRowTemplate>
            <Button Color="Color.Success" Clicked="context.NewCommand.Clicked">New</Button>
            <Button Color="Color.Primary" Clicked="context.EditCommand.Clicked">Edit</Button>
            <Button Color="Color.Danger" Clicked="context.DeleteCommand.Clicked">Delete</Button>
            <Button Color="Color.Link" Clicked="context.ClearFilterCommand.Clicked">Clear Filter</Button>
        </ButtonRowTemplate>
```

The code works but only in the cached memory (context).  The changes are not propagated to the DB.  The API's I have written in the past use a straight update command similar to:

```
replaceResponse = await this.container.ReplaceItemAsync<T>(itemBody, itemBody.Id, new PartitionKey(itemBody.someID));
```

I am trying to sync the cache / context with the DB.  I have unsuccessfully tried to tie in a database update in parallel with the cache update using code similar to the code above.   Is this correct or is there a more serial way of updating the cache and then pushing those context changes to the DB?  In a sense, committing those changes.

I should also add that I am using the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core.  I would like to get the code working before moving to the Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos library.  I appreciate any assistance as I am getting back into front end development using Blazor.

Comment: Is your question regarding migration from V2 to V3? Or are you asking when does an operation commit?

Comment: When (how) does the operation commit?

Comment: This is a network call, if after calling `await` you get a response, and the response was a success, then it is commited.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but the question in my mind is it right?  More specifically was there an easier way to do it like commit the changes from the cache?

WHAT I DID

First, I did a little more digging into the Blazorise Grid component.  There is a parameter called RowInserted.  I believe this triggers a function after a row is add to the cache.

```
<DataGrid TItem="PowderInfo"
              Data="@powderlist"
              @bind-SelectedRow="@selectedLoad"
              RowInserted="AddNewDoc"
```

Then I added a new function called AddNewDoc to the page code.

```
    protected async Task AddNewDoc()
    {
        var item = new PowderInfo();
        item = this.powderlist.ElementAt(this.powderlist.Count() - 1);
        item.id = this.powderlist.Count().ToString();
        await getPowderData.AddNewDocument(item);
    }
```

- item is an instance of my document type.
- powderlist is my local cache.
- this.powderlist.ElementAt gets the cached item that was just
  added just added.
- item.id is propagated using the count value.
- finally, a call to the DAL's AddNewDocument with the new document.

```
 public async Task AddNewDocument(PowderInfo item)
        {
            await CosmosDBRepository<PowderInfo>.CreateItemAsync(item, "Powders");
        }
```

And now my database is updated.  But again, since the cache is coming from the DAL, was there another way to update the DB?